# How to save and load offline maps efficiently when using MKTileOverlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps, mkmapview, mktileoverlay

I am wanting to display and also cache map tiles for offline use from a chosen service such as Open Street Maps. This seems to be easy since `iOS7` and it works using:

```
static NSString * const template = @"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
self.tileOverlay = [[ZSSTileOverlay alloc] initWithURLTemplate:template];
self.tileOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.tileOverlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
```

In my `MKTileOverLay` subclass I am overriding `loadTileAtPath:result:` to download the tiles and save them to disk for offline use. Later I will implement a method for users to choose what part of the map to download:

```
- (void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path result:(void (^)(NSData *tileData, NSError *error))result {

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tile.openstreetmap.org/%li/%li/%li.png", (long)path.z, (long)path.x, (long)path.y];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (data == nil) {
            // Load a default tile here
        } else {

            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
            result(data, nil);
            NSString *pathForWritting = [self pathToWriteImage:path];
            NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)path.y];
            [self saveImage:image withFileName:fileName ofType:@"png" inDirectory:pathForWritting];

        }
    }];

}

- (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image withFileName:(NSString *)imageName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath {
    // Create folder structure if it doesn't exist
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:directoryPath]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }
    if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        NSString *fullPath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"png"]];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];

    } else if ([[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [[extension lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"jpeg"]) {
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", imageName, @"jpg"]] options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];
    }
}

- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                   inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

- (NSString *)pathToWriteImage:(MKTileOverlayPath)path {

    NSString *pathFolder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tiles/%li/%li", (long)path.z, (long)path.x];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [self applicationDocumentsDirectory].path, pathFolder];

}
```

This works exactly how I would expect, and it saves the images into appropriately named folders:

[image]

Now, the real question here is threefold:

- Is saving the tiles to disk, and then loading them back when offline a good idea? Or should these be saved in something like an SQL Lite DB?
- It seems that tiles are automatically loaded by `MapKit`, why is it necessary to download them a second time in `loadTitleAtPath:`? Is there no way to get the tiles that `MKMapView` is already loading?
- What is a good method (ignoring how I have done it here, that was for testing) for allowing the user to choose what parts of the map they would like to download and what map levels? Current rect with all zoom levels higher than current one?

Comment: I used something similar to above as well as a tile caching algorithm to download tiles at the current zoom level and below.

Comment: @NicHubbard can you please share me code for load map from offline(document directory)

Comment: @TejasArdeshna You need to override `loadTileAtPath:result:` and provide the `UIImage` data that you have saved locally.